# Dividing two integers results 0, while I should get 1

Tags: c, scanf

I was suppose to get distance and speed from user and to return the time.
Here's the code I did:

```
int main()
{
    int distance, speed;
    scanf("%d,%d", &distance, &speed);
    printf("%d\n", distance / speed);
    printf("%d hours and %d minutes", (distance/speed), (distance / speed)%60);
}
```

For the values:

> 10 10

I receive `0` as output.

Comment: Format your code! Then, what values do you enter? Show the output.

Comment: Did you enter `10,10`, or `10 10` (with or without comma?). If the latter, then `scanf(3)` failed to match everything so you are most likely using uninitialized variables. You should at least check that `scanf(3)` returned 2.

Comment: **[edit] your code in a way that should keep the existing answers valid. Never _change_ the original question, _add_ the extra info as a prt of edit.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is, you did not check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure it's success.

By property, the format string supplied with `scanf()` should *exactly* match with the input, otherwise, due to matching failure, the receiving arguments won't get the expected value.

With a format string like

```
scanf("%d,%d", &distance, &speed);
```

an input

> 10 10

is not *proper*, you need to enter like

> 10,10

to match the `,` in the format string.

Otherwise, you can remove the `,` from the format string also, and provide the input in space-delimited format.

---

[Edit]:

To *enforce* a floating point division, please chnage your statement to

```
    printf("%f\n", ( (float)distance / speed ) );
    printf("%f hours and %d minutes", ( (float)distance / speed ), (distance / speed)%60);
```

Comment: oh ye... noobish me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter `10,10` because that's what you require with your `scanf()`.

Then of course your calculation are incorrect.  You'll get `1` and `1` for both hours and minutes.